# Android: How to call apis in mobile with sub-domain from local system

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, uri, subdomain

I have a Rails application running in my laptop and an android application on phone. I want to call apis of rails application where routes are namespace with sub-domain.

My api look like below:

```
http://api.localhost:3000/login (With sub-domain)
```

When I replace localhost with ip address. It will work in browser but in android application it gives me **Android java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect**. But when I namespace without sub-domain it works.

```
http://192.168.1.101:3000/api/login (Works fine)
```

What is the correct URI with sub-domain ?

```
http://api.192.168.101:3000/login  (Gives above error)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve the problem is if you have a domain registered. You can add a DNS entry for hostname `api.192.168.101`.

If not, you have few options.

1. Setup your wireless router to resolve the hostname `api.192.168.101` to `192.168.1.101`. I am assuming, your phone's DNS server is your wireless router. If your wireless router does not support adding local DNS entries checkout the next option.
2. You have to add the entries to "/etc/hosts" file of your Android phone. It is easy for rooted phones

I suggest you consider buying a domain from a good vendor who provides you a decent DNS management console.